# Explanation of matrix similarity $B=P^{-1}AP$

Tags: linear-algebra

So two matrices $A,B$ are similar iff there exists some matrix $P$ such that $B=P^{-1}AP$ but could someone explain what this really means? I understand that P is the change of basis matrix but could someone maybe try to simply explain what this multiplication is doing to A?

Comment: Welcome to MSE. The sentence "two matrices are similar iff $B=P^{-1}AP$" makes no sense. What are $A$, $B$, and $P$?

Comment: If $B x = y$ then $AP x = Py$. Does that help with seeing the "change of basis" aspect?

Comment: Transform the data, operate on the data and transform the answer back.

Comment: While conjugation is useful tool in many areas of mathematics, in beginner linear algebra it should be helpful to think of it as change of basis or change of coordinates.

Answer (score 0):

Algebraically the construction with $PXP^{-1}$ is highly useful and called the conjugation of $X$ by $P$ and it shows up in group theory as well. This is because conjugation is an [automorphism](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Automorphism) so it preserves many of the interesting properties of the space you're working with. One way to think about automorphism of a vector space is as a change of basis since it preserves the space but changes the coordinates you use to represent the vectors in it. Automorphisms can also be thought of as a relabeling of the elements in a space, so they're the same thing just with new names.

Another useful property of conjugates is that if $B=PXP^{-1}$ then $B^n = PX^nP^{-1}$. This will be useful later as you can sometimes choose a $P$ that makes $B$ a diagonal matrix, thus simplifying the calculation of $B^n$ which allows you to then calculate $X^n$ using significantly less operations than doing the full matrix multiplication so it has a practical side as well.

Answer (score 0):

The map $B \mapsto PBP^{-1}$ is called the *conjugation* map. Is essentially an automorfism (biyective operator), in an algebraic structure —in your case, vector spaces.

Conjugations have many, many interrsting an useful aplications. The similarity of matrices is an special case of conjugation, and has the property that if $B=PXP^{-1}$ then $$B^n = P X^n P,$$ equality that is fundamental when calculating the exponential of a matrix (and hence, solving systems of differential equations).